# x86 TargetPlatform with XBAPs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dependencies, xbap, target-platform

I've got a XAML Browser Hosted Application (XBAP) project that has a dependency on another project that is x86 only.  All sorts of hell breaks loose at runtime (with respect to grabbing the DLLs) if I leave the target platform as "Any CPU".  However, if I switch the XBAP project to target x86, I get the following compile time error:

> Error 7 - Cannot build a
>   platform-specific XAML Browser
>   Application. If HostInBrowser property
>   is set to 'True', either do not set
>   the PlatformTarget property or set it
>   to 'AnyCpu'.

Is there a work around for this?  Or am I going to have to figure out some horrific multi-process + IPC solution for this*?

<sub>*The mere thought of which fills me with terror</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dependent .dll don't have any links to win32 native dll's you could dissasemble it in Reflector and recompile it as Any CPU, or get an Any CPU version if possible. If it has win32 links, then I think you have to split it into multi procs as you suggest.