# xaml not detected in reference when using Framework 3.5 and Platform x86

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, dll, target-platform

I am using WPF Web Browser at the moment and I'm not able to run my program because it keeps on giving an Error "**Cannot build a platform-specific XAML Browser Application...**" 
My program is set to .net framework of 3.5 and should also be set to targeted platform of x86 because my .dll are 32bit and framework 3.5 compatible..
.dll is not returning anything when using 'ANY CPU'

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You can avoid this error by targeting Any CPU on configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

As [MikaelSvenson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633789/2819451) mentioned in his comments

> If your dependent .dll don't have any links to win32 native dll's you
>   could dissasemble it in Reflector and recompile it as Any CPU, or get
>   an Any CPU version if possible. If it has win32 links, then I think
>   you have to split it into multi procs.